# Creating file manager in php

Tags: php

i want to create php small file manager

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
    @unlink($_GET['del']);
}
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
    $pieces = explode("/", $_GET['download']);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$pieces[2]);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($_GET['download']));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($_GET['download']);
}
if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
    $directory = $_GET['dir'];
} else {
    $directory = "./";
}
$dir = @opendir($directory);
echo '<a href="?">returntomain</a> <br />';
while ($file = readdir($dir))
{
    if (is_dir($file))
    {
        $directory = $file;
        if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
            $directory = $_GET['dir'] . '/' . $file . '/';
        }
        echo 'dir:  <a href="?dir='.$directory.'">'.$file.'</a> <br />';
    } else {
        $filedel = $file;
        $filesize = @filesize($file);
        $filename = $file;
        $filedownload = $file;
        if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
            $filedel = $_GET['dir'] . '/' . $file;
            $filesize = @filesize($_GET['dir'] . '/' . $file);
            $filename = $_GET['dir'] . '/' . $file;
            $filedownload = $_GET['dir'] . '/' . $file;
        }
        echo 'file: <a href="'.$filename.'">'.$file.'</a> '.$filesize.'bytes <a href="?del='.$filedel.'">[delete]</a> '.'<a href="?download='.$filedownload.'">[download]</a> <br />';  
    }

}

closedir($dir);
?>
```

but it have 2 errors
the first one when i access folder
in this folder not all sub folders are shown
like
Dir:Test
   file:test
but it is subfolder
and the second one the download and acsessed 2 or more folders the name is not shown
like
Dir: ..
  Dir: ..
    File: test.txt

Comment: what happens when someone visits `http://yoursite/yourpage.php?del=/var/www/index.php`?

Comment: `@unlink($_GET['del']);` wow...

Comment: `?dir=../../../` and suddenly you can list/delete anything on your entire system?

Comment: im using it in local host not internet and im using windows not linux

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Hi, this is your browser, let met prefetch these links for you :-)

Comment: @jeroen I dont get it S-;

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Just adding to your comment really; there are extensions that prefetch all links on a page and the delete actions are links here, see one of the very last lines...

Comment: @jeroen riiiighhht.. get ya now hehe

Comment: And what's your question about this? What keeps you from fixing the problems?